# Using TinyMCE editor to hold image as base 64 before form submission

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm making a Javascript app that collects the contents of a TinyMCE editor and sends it all to the server in a single post. I'm trying to allow the user to upload images into the editor, but I can't figure out how to do it without submitting the images at the time they're uploaded to a server-side image handler. I need a way to submit all images and text in one post.

I don't know a lot about handling images, but my thinking is that I can accomplish this by collecting the images as base64 strings and sending them along with the rest of the html input. First question: Is my line of thinking correct?

Second question: How do I accomplish this? I've managed to encode an uploaded image as base 64,  but the TinyMCE editor image upload dialog box gets stuck open as if it's still uploading even after I already have the base 64 string.

index.html:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: '.texteditor',
  plugins: 'autoresize code hr image link lists media searchreplace table charmap anchor help',
  images_upload_url: 'scripts/image_upload.js',
  images_upload_handler: function () {
    console.log("heres the image_upload_handler"); //This never fires
    upload_image();
  },
  automatic_uploads: true,
});
```

image_upload.js:

```
function upload_image(event) {

    const dropzone = document.getElementsByClassName('tox-dropzone')[0];
    var fileInput = dropzone.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    var files = fileInput.files;
    var file = files[0];
    console.log("File " + file.name + " is " + file.size + " bytes in size");
    getBase64(file);
}

function getBase64(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function () {
        console.log(reader.result);  //This successfully prints the base 64 string, but the editor's dialog box won't close and the image never appears in the editor
    };
    reader.onerror = function (error) {
        console.log('Error: ', error);
    };
}
```

When I upload an image using the editor, the result is this:
[image]

The console shows the image encoded as base 64, but the dialog box won't close. What do I need to do differently? Vanilla Javascript, please.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand the purpose of `images_upload_url` - that parameter should point to a server side endpoint that processes the Base64 image and returns a new URL that is used in the `<img>` tag's `src` attribute for the image.

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/upload-images/

You also should not use `images_upload_url` and `images_upload_handler` - they are two different ways for TinyMCE to POST the image for processing to a server.  As you have seen, if you define `images_upload_url` TinyMCE won't try to use `images_upload_handler`.  You really only need `images_upload_handler` if our `images_upload_url` is not doing what you need.

The documentation page I referenced above should have the default code we execute when using `images_upload_url`.

I would note that you ask if you can send the Base64 images with the content when you submit the data.  You can absolutely do that but the HTML payload will be significantly larger as the image binary content is now part of the HTML itself as opposed to stored externally as an image on a server (e.g. a PNG file).

Base64 images also block the browser from rendering any other HTML on the page while they process the Base64 data - this is generally considered bad for page load times.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now I know to only use the images_upload_handler. But I'm still not clear on what I need to do in my handler to make the upload dialog spinner stop spinning and close itself (or be receptive to user input to close it). I've read the documentation you referenced, but I still don't understand.

Comment: The server side code needs to store the image somewhere and return JSON that provides the new location where the image is located.. As mentioned on the referenced documentation page:   "This server-side upload handler script must return a JSON object containing a 'location' property. This property represents the remote location and filename of the newly uploaded image."

`{ location : '/uploaded/image/path/image.png' }`